# How to shift a linear layout when soft keyboard is ON

Tags: android

I made a similar dialog box (xml layout), that exists in a linear layout. and i want this linear layout to be shifted when soft keyboard is ON.

[image: LinearLayout shifted when soft keyboard is ON]
EDIT: I want it to appear just like the WhatsApp dialog box is appearing in the image.

SOLVED:

The problem was because the PARENT was RelativeLayout ( which was occupying the entire screen ) , therefore, after adding what @Enigma suggested below in the manifest file, and removing the parent layout which is relative layout and making LinearLayout containing the dialog box only, the parent.

Comment: use adjustResize in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In AndroidManifest.xml for that particular Activity, add this attribute `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"`

That must work.

Comment: I just tried it, it didn't work, actually the dialog box didn't change its position(stayed in the center of the layout) , but the height change, it became very small, and views are no longer visible!

Comment: It Worked! The problem was because i was putting this LinearLayout INSIDE a RelativeLayout. So I removed the entire RelativeLayout occupying all the screen! And I kept ONLY the LinearLayout! It means that the RelativeLayout is no longer the parent, the parent is now LinearLayout.

Comment: I'm curious how that makes any difference. But glad it's working for you.

Comment: Yes it makes a difference because RelativeLayout was match_parent for height and width. Therefore, when trying to shift it, imagine.. you just can't shift something that's set to match_parent right? ;) Thanks for ur help, without `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"` it  doesn't work.